# Is every nonexpansive retract of a Hilbert space closed and convex?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Given a closed and convex subset $C\subset H$ of a Hilbert space $H$, the metric projection is a nonexpansive retraction of $H$ onto $C$. This implies that every closed and convex subset of a Hilbert space is a nonexpansive retract. Is the converse true as well, i.e. is every nonexpansive retract closed and convex?

In case the answer is no, is there a characterisation of the nonexpansive retracts of a Hilbert space?

---

A nonexpansive retraction is a nonexpansive mapping $H\to C$ which restricted on $C$ is the identity. A nonexpansive retract of $H$ is a subset onto which there exists a nonexpansive retraction. A nonexpansive mapping is a mapping $f$ which satisfies $$\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq \|x-y\|$$ for all $x,y\in H$.

Comment: nonexpansive means 1-Lipschitz?

Comment: @YCor yes, I will edit it into the question.

Comment: If $f$ is a 1-Lipschitz self-map of a uniquely geodesic metric space, the space of fixed points of $f$ is clearly closed and convex. So the answer is yes.

Comment: @YCor: I see, thanks. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.